# HTML5 video seeking on iPad

Tags: ipad, html5-video, seekbar

I have an HTML5 video player with a custom seek bar, that's working great on the iPhone (playing inline) and on the browser.

It plays great on the iPad too and the seek bar is updated as the movie plays, but for some reason, I can't seek.

All of the values are correct and I'm trying to set:

```
myPlayer.currentTime = XX;
```

Unfortunately, the iPad refuses to set the .currentTime attribute.

From what I can gather **the difference** between the browser and iPad is that **on the browser I get:**

```
myPlayer.networkState = 3
myPlayer.readyState = 4
```

**On the iPad I get:**

```
myPlayer.networkState = 2
myPlayer.readyState = 3
```

It's exactly the same code, running a local MP4 video.

Any idea why this is happening?

Cheers,
Andre

Comment: Could you post the code that is setting the current time. I'm able to do this without much difficulty.

Comment: Here: videoPlayerElement.currentTime = x * videoPlayerElement.duration / scrubberBg.width(); ... this works in the browser (several of them) and on the iPad, the value traces out ok, bu the property isn't set. I'm running 3.2

Comment: I've found that the setting `video.currentTime` on iOS seems to be gated behind a user action. Issuing an `alert()` or a touch event before setting the `currentTime` seems to provide the correct response - except of course for the user interaction it requires.

Answer (score 6):

I've had all kinds of problems getting JavaScript to control audio elements, and a lot of frustration with the currentTime property, along with Apple's restrictions on what constitutes direct user initiation of events.

It wouldn't surprise me if there were some kind of weird bug with JavaScript & HTML5 video playback on the iPad (or "feature" that's undocumented), which requires a workaround.  From my experience, the iPad has a unique way of doing things than what's in the official documentation.

You should check the **error**, **buffered**, **seekable**, and **seeking** properties of the video element.  Looking at your readyState & networkState values, the iPad seems to think that the video has not been completely loaded - which is odd for a local resource.

**buffered** and **seekable** should be equal to the time range of your entire video.  seeking should be TRUE.  That should at least give you a little more information about the problem.

Have you tested it with other videos?  It *might* be that there is some kind of encoding problem with the video that the iPad has a problem with.

Other than that - there was a bug in a previous iPad OS version that broke the ability to set the currentTime property.  Are you using the latest OS version?

Comment: I'm using 3.2 (because I can't limit it to the latest) and I have tried a different video source, with the same problem :/

Answer (score 5):

This issue is related with value used on the `video.currentTime` property. On my specific case I fixed the problem by always making sure I was  using floating point numbers with **1 decimal digit** during the seek.

Setting `video.currentTime` to ZERO on iOS 3.2 will indeed seek the video to the beginning but the value won't update after that - `timeupdate` event is still dispatched normally but if you try to read `currentTime` it will always return the same value.

To seek to the begin of the video use `0.1` instead of `0`, to seek to `12.2345` use `12.2`.

PS: you can use `(+(12.2345).toFixed(1))` to limit the number of decimal digits to 1.

Comment: I have the same issue and tried rounding as per above, but it doesn't seem to work on IOS 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

Kyle's answer is a good one. I would add, **you can't assume the `seekable` attribute is filled in after any particular event**. This means you can't wait for events like `loadedmetadata`, `canplay`, or any other and assume that you're able to set `currentTime` safely at that point.

It seems the safest way to do it is to check `seekable` after every video-related event, and if it encompasses the time you want to seek to, set `currentTime` at that point. On iPad, `seekable` may not be filled until after the `canplaythrough` event, which is quite late.

See [my blog post](http://adamernst.com/post/6570213273/seeking-an-html5-video-player-on-the-ipad) for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue - here are the properties in my case:

```
UIWebView - iPad Simulator
duration=4.861666679382324
startTime=0
currentTime=4.861666679382324
buffered(1)=[0-0]
seekable(0)=
seeking=false
error=null
readystate=4
networkstate=3

Chrome:
duration=4.9226298332214355
startTime=0
currentTime=4.9226298332214355
buffered(1)=[0-4.9226298332214355]
seekable(1)=[0-4.9226298332214355]
seeking=false
error=null
readystate=4
networkstate=1
```

so - nothing is getting buffered and nothing is seekable.  i am playing a local clip from the resources directory of an iPad bundle, via a UIWebView.

In my case, all i need is to reset to the top of the video after each play, and I was able to accomplish this via a call to "load()"