# missing html5 video "ended" event on iPad

Tags: ipad, html5-video

Sometimes my HTML5 video does not generate an "ended" event on the iPad.  Seems only to happen when I omit the "controls" attribute and start playback from javascript.  It usually works fine the first time, but the second time the video plays out but does not generate an "ended" event.  I do call "load()" after each playback in order to reset to the beginning of the clip (because seeking doesn't seem to work at all - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768529/html5-video-seeking-on-ipad)).  I have a workaround, which is to track "timeupdate" events and perform my end-of-play actions when `vid.currentTime>=vid.duration`, but I was wondering if anyone else had experienced this problem.  Some relevant code follows.

Cheers
-Chris

The document onload function:

```
function load() {
    var vid = document.getElementById('vid');
    vid.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        alert('video ended');
        vid.load();
    },false);
}
```

The html:

```
<body onload="load();">
<h1>HTML5 Video Test</h1>
<input type="submit" value="Play" onclick="document.getElementById('vid').play();">
<video id="vid" src="test.mov" width="640" height="480"></video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `load()` to force the seek. If you set `video.currentTime` to `0.1` instead of `0` the video will jump to the beginning and the `ended` event will still dispatch properly. (Tested on iOS 3.2 and 4.2)

Comment: Thank you!  Do you know if this documented somewhere?  Or is it a bug?  seek(0) works in desktop browsers.

Comment: it's a bug, I've "documented" it on my own blog: http://blog.millermedeiros.com/2011/03/html5-video-issues-on-the-ipad-and-how-to-solve-them/